# Determining te probability that a message can not be corrected

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

A bit error occurs with probability $10^{-7}$  . A message consists of 8000 bits. Upto three bit errors can be corrected at the receiver with FEC (Forward Error Correction) code in the message. Determine the probability that a message can not be corrected at the receiver.

I thougt that a message contain three or less error with probability

$$\begin{align}
p & = \binom{8000}{3}\left(\frac{1}{10^7}\right)^3\left(1-\frac{1}{10^7}\right)^{7997} + \binom{8000}{2}\left(\frac{1}{10^7}\right)^2\left(1-\frac{1}{10^7}\right)^{7998} + \binom{8000}{1}\left(\frac{1}{10^7}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{10^7}\right)^{7999} + \left(1-\frac{1}{10^7}\right)^{8000}
\end{align}$$

so probability that a message can not be corrected is 
$$
1-p
$$

Is this answer right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\checkmark$ Yes, it's a binomial distribution.  That's *entirely correct* and *relatively* easy to calculate for small $k$ such as this.

I'd recommend using a Normal approximation if you need to do this for larger $k$.